# Is this proof about the "Maximum Chunk Product Problem" (my own name for it) sufficient and clear?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

**- Question:**
For $L \in \mathbb{N}$, how do you choose $[x_i]$ so as to maximize $\prod x_i$ where $\sum x_i = L$ and $x_i \in \mathbb{N}$? (The number of "chunks" $x_i$ can be whatever you want.)

**- Answer:**
If $L \bmod 3 = 0$, then $[x_i] = [x_0, x_1, x_2, \dotsc] = [3, 3, 3, \dotsc]$.
If $L \bmod 3 = 1$, then $[x_i] = [x_0, x_1, x_2, \dotsc] = [4, 3, 3, \dotsc]$.
If $L \bmod 3 = 2$, then $[x_i] = [x_0, x_1, x_2, \dotsc] = [2, 3, 3, \dotsc]$.

**- Problem:**
Prove it.

**- Proof:**
First, some terminology. A "partition" refers to the choice of $[x_i]$, so "optimal partition for $L$" mean the choice of $[x_i]$ which has the maximal product across all partitions of $L$.

Next, some quick clarifications and assertions about optimal partitions to cover some edge cases.
(a) For partitions with the same product, we will default to the partition with fewer chunks. Basically, this means instead of using $2$ chunks of $2$, we would just use $1$ chunk of $4$, because the sum is the same ($4$) and the product is the same ($4$) but $1$ chunk of $4$ is fewer chunks than $2$ and $2$.
(b) For $L > 1$ we will never have a chunk of size $1$, since it would not increase the product (multiplying by $1$ doesn't change a number) but adding that $1$ to any other chunk would increase the product.
(c) For $L > 4$ we will never have a chunk of size $L$, since we can trivially do better by using chunks of size $L-2$ and $2$ (with product $(L-2)*2$). This is because $L > 4$ ==> $2L-4 > L$ ==> $2(L-2) > L$.

Now, we will use strong induction on the form of the optimal partition. The induction hypothesis is that the optimal partition for each of $1$ to $l-1$ is of the form described in "Answer" above. We will assume this hypothesis and use it to show that the optimal partition for $l$ must also be of this form. Then we need only to show that the hypothesis holds for the first few integers, and then it follows that it holds for all integers.

Base Case:
By exhausting all possibilities (I won't write them all out), we can manually get the optimal partitions for the first $7$ values of $l$ and see that the hypothesis holds:

```
L | optimal partition
--|------------------
2 | 2
3 | 3
4 | 4
5 | 3, 2
6 | 3, 3
7 | 3, 4
```

Inductive Step:
First, let's show that there can only be chunks of $2$, $3$, and $4$ in the optimal partition of $l$.
There can't be a chunk of size $1$ because of (b).
Assume for the sake of contradiction that there is a chunk of size $x_i > 4$. We can get a partition of $l$ with a greater product by replacing that chunk with *its* optimal partition (since we know from (c) that that chunk's size's optimal partition cannot simply be a singleton chunk equal to its own size), so the partition could not have been optimal, which is a contradiction, so we know all chunks must be $2$, $3$, or $4$.
Then, let's show that there cannot be more than $1$ non-$3$ chunk.
Assume for sake of contradiction that there is more than $1$ non-$3$ chunk. There will be either $2$ chunks of $4$ or $1$ chunk of $2$ and $1$ chunk of $4$ (if there were $2$ chunks of $2$, we would have replaced them with $1$ chunk of $4$). $[4, 4]$ can be replaced by $[3, 3, 2]$, and $[2, 4]$ can be replaced by $[3, 3]$, again contradicting the optimality of the original partition, this time showing that there cannot have been more than $1$ non-$3$ chunk.
Thus, the optimal partition must be made only of chunks of $2$, $3$, and $4$, and there can be at most $1$ non-$3$ chunk. This is another way of exactly describing the form described in "Answer" above, proving the induction hypothesis and completing the proof. $\square$

Comment: All the details seem covered. I think things would be tidier if $4$ were not allowed.